# Is Transaction required for Firestore increment, arrayUnion and arrayRemove functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore functions `increment`, `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` are very power functions to update data. Can we use these functions directly with `update` and not use `transactions`? Do these `FieldValue` functions take care of simultaneous update on a Firestore Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these `increment`, `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` operators require the use of a client-side transaction. Instead they send the operation to the server, and perform an atomic update there - ensuring there are no conflicting updates automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So I guess if I am updating 2 fields of a document, one with let's say a Date and another with increment function, the Date field will still need a transaction to avoid data override. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Also, I guess function FieldValue.delete() takes care of conflicting updates automatically. Sorry for putting the doubts in the comments. I just forgot to add in the main question.

Comment: 1) If the new value of the date field depends on its current value, you'll indeed need a transaction. But that is unrelated to the operators you asked about. 2) `FieldValue.delete()` indeed also is executed atomically on the server.

Comment: On the update of Date type field, I think I can user FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as this is also a server-side function and executed atomically on the server.